# Two word token using PLY in Python

Tags: python, compiler-construction, lexer, ply

I am writing a compiler as part of a lab excercise and have chosen to do it in Python using PLY. I have spent some time trying to work this particular problem out and have reached a dead end as have my lab helpers.

In the language I have to write, declarators are specified with two words "was a". For example:

`x was a number and x became 5.`

is equal to

`int x; x = 5;`

When parsing with PLY, I have put 'was a' as a reserved word

```
reserved = {
    ...
    'was a'       : 'DECLARATOR',
    ...
}
```

But when I parse with the PLY lexer, it treats 'was' and 'a' as separate tokens

How can I parse `was a` as a token of type 'DECLARATOR' without the PLY lexer splitting it up?

If any of that is unclear let me know and I will try and answer any questions as best I can

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: Why not simply make it two tokens?

Comment: Eventually that's what I did. I was told it should be able to handle two words, but then this was corrected by another professor. You should never need to use two words in a token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never have to use two words in a token. Instead split them into two seperate tokens and ensure your language enforces that one is always followed by the other.

e.g. implement a `'was' : 'DECLARATOR_WAS'` token and an `'a' : 'DECLARATOR_A'` token.